# Caliburn.Micro - How to ActivateItem from class other than the Conductor

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I've composed the UI of my Caliburn.Micro application such that toolbar buttons have their own View and ViewModel.

In the examples I've seen, to activate a new screen, a method in the shell calls `Conductor.ActivateItem`, passing in the viewmodel instance, however in my case the `ToolbarButtonViewModel.Submit()` method is on a class that *isn't* the shell.

What's the best way of activating screens from a class **other** than the shell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should consider using the EventAggregator. Create a message which the main conductor handles and send it from the tool bar vm. When the message is recieved by the main conductor, activate the screen that it specifies.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case for inter-viewmodel communication (between the toolbar view model, and the shell viewmodel). Depending on how loosely coupled you wish the code to be, you could either:

1. Use standard .NET events. Assuming the `ShellViewModel` has a reference to the `ToolBarViewModel` instance, subscribe to the `ToolBarViewModel`'s event in the `ShellViewModel` to detect the submit, and pass the new screen instance to the delegate instance.
2. Use a mediator pattern (such as the `EventAggregator` included in Caliburn.Micro). Subscribe to the event in the `ShellViewModel`, and publish the event in the `ToolBarViewModel`
3. Actually conduct the `ToolBarViewModel` in the `ShellViewModel` (presumably you'll have to use the `Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive` type). The `ToolBarViewModel` will then be a `Screen` and have a `Parent` property (yes, this is ugly).

Comment: Ooooh EventAggregator! Now that could be the way to do it... :)